# Custom Order By - 00 first, followed by 0,1,2,3... - Laravel / MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Take the following values

```
ABC3
ABC2
ABC1
ABC4
ABC0
ABC00
```

I have the following

```
return $this->hasMany('Item')
    ->orderBy('code');
```

Which returns the items in the following sequence:

```
ABC0
ABC00
ABC1
ABC2
ABC3
ABC4
```

But I want ABC00 at the top of the list, what's the best way to do this?

Comment: `ORDER BY LENGTH(value) DESC, value ASC`. Convert this to Laravel syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a SQL statement [[MYSQL flavor](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qQLivssAZTrmfNu3UMLNFQ/0)] like

```sql
SELECT code 
    FROM [some_table] 
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(code, 4) AS UNSIGNED) ASC, LENGTH(code) DESC;
```

In Eloquent, this will be

```php
return $this->hasMany('Item')
    ->orderByRaw('CAST(SUBSTRING(code, 4) AS UNSIGNED) ASC, LENGTH(code) DESC');
```